# Aptana Scriptdoc doesn't show up in Code Assist

Tags: javascript, eclipse, aptana

I've followed all the instructions to get my code comments to show up in Code Assist but I'm not having any luck. Currently using Aptana 3 plugin inside of Eclipse (could that be the issue?)

```
myObj = {
/** 
* Gets the current foo 
* @param {String} fooId The unique identifier for the foo.
* @return {Object} Returns the current foo.
*/
getFoo: function (fooID) {
    return bar[fooID];
}
```

}

When I have the above code, the function shows up in code assist, but there is no documentation associated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out on the Aptana support forums that their Scriptdoc setup doesn't support undeclared vars.

If I change the above code to:

```
var myObj = {
    /** 
    * Gets the current foo 
    * @param {String} fooId The unique identifier for the foo.
    * @return {Object} Returns the current foo.
    */
    getFoo: function (fooID) {
        return bar[fooID];
    }
}
```

then everything works