# Aptana 3 ScriptDoc - @Return not working in Code Assist

Tags: php, aptana

I found this question that had been answered, but it didn't solve my problem:
[Aptana Scriptdoc doesn't show up in Code Assist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193725/aptana-scriptdoc-doesnt-show-up-in-code-assist)

Using the PHP equivalent of their example...

```
/**
 * Gets the current foo
 * @param {String} $fooId The unique identifier for the foo.
 * @return {Object} Returns the current foo. 
 */
public function getFoo($fooId) {
    return $bar[$fooId];
}
```

However, the documenation provided looks like this (extra ending braces included):

```
getFoo($fooId)
Gets the current foo

@param String $fooId The unique identifier for the foo.
@return Object}
Resolved return types: Object}
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The @return type should not be wrapped with curly brackets.

Your doc should look like this:

```
/**
 * Gets the current foo
 * @param String $fooId The unique identifier for the foo.
 * @return Object Returns the current foo. 
 */
public function getFoo($fooId) {
    return $bar[$fooId];
}
```

The parsing of the return type follows the [PHPDoc @return rules](http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.return.pkg.html).

This also means you can have a mixed return type, which will give you code-assist suggestions from multiple types.

For example:

```
/**
 * @return MyClass|PDO doc doc doc 
 */
```

Cheers